# The centralizer of a product of two elements in a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, monoid

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, $R$ a commutative $k$-algebra, and $E$ the monoid of $k$-endomorphisms of $R$. 
Assume that $e_i \in E$, $1 \leq i \leq 2$, has centralizer $C_{e_i}$ in $E$
 ($C_{e_i}$ is of course a sub-monoid of $E$).

Is it possible to know what is the centralizer of $e:=e_1e_2$?
Clearly, $C_{e_1} \cap C_{e_2}$ is contained in $C_{e}$, the centralizer of $e$
(but $C_{e}$ may strictly contain $C_{e_1} \cap C_{e_2}$).

(What if we further assume that $e_1e_2=e_2e_1$?).

Any relevant ideas/hints are welcome.
Perhaps [the first answer in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272161/a-structural-proof-that-ax-xa-forms-a-monoid) is relevant to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is very much that is interesting you can say about this without adding some strong additional hypotheses.  As an illustrative example, suppose $e_1$ is an automorphism of $R$ and $e_2=e_1^{-1}$.  Then $e_1e_2=e_2e_1$, but $C_{e_1e_2}$ consists of all of $E$ since $e_1e_2=1$.  On the other hand, $C_{e_1}\cap C_{e_2}=C_{e_1}$ will typically be smaller than $E$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, do you know of a 'not too strong' condition which will imply $C_{e_1} \cap C_{e_2}=C_{e_1e_2}$? Also, I am not sure I understand why, in your example, $C_{e_1} \subseteq C_{e_2}$; am I missing something trivial?

Comment: I don't know of any such condition, I'm afraid.  In my example, if $fe_1=e_1f$ then composing on the right and left with $e_2$ gives $e_2f=fe_2$.

Comment: Thanks again. So I was missing something trivial..