# Find all polynomials $P(x)$ such that $P(x^2+1)=P(x)^2+1$ and $P(0)=0$

Tags: polynomials

> Find all polynomials $P(x)$ such that $P(x^2+1)=P(x)^2+1$ and $P(0)=0$.

It's almost the same question as this: [Find all polynomials $P$ such that $P(x^2+1)=P(x)^2+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271337/find-all-polynomials-p-such-that-px21-px21).

But here I have the condition $P(0)=0$.

Comment: Referring to the other question: It follows easily by induction that, for all $P(x)$ of positive even degree, $P(0)>0$.  The constant solutions are not zero, so the only polynomial for your condition is the one of odd degree.

Comment: Yup, based on the answers in the previous post that you linked, and @Michael's point, you already have your answer.

Comment: If $P(0)=0$ then $P(0^2+1)=P(1)=P(0)^2+1=1$. 

Then, $P(1^2+1)=P(2)=1+1=2$.

Then, $P(2^2+1)=P(5)=2+1=3$.

Then, $P(5^2+1)=P(26)=4$.

And so on, so, if there exists such polynomial I believe it should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume coefficients $c_0,c_1, \cdots$ such that:
$$ P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i$$
Coefficients of $P(x^2+1)$ and $P(x)^2+1$ are easy to compute in terms of $\{c_k\}$. Do that and then set them to be equal for each coefficient of the equation. This way $P(0)=0$ just tells us $c_0=0$. Left hand side will obviously have all odd coeffs = 0 which will likely make it help starting with those ones.

Also, start with lower exponents, as fewer coefficients will be involved there.