# Find the polynomials

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Find all polynomial $P$ satisfying $P(x^2+1)=P(x)^2+1$

Attemp: I haven't proved it, but i suspect that this are all of them:
$p(x) \equiv \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$p(x) \equiv \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

and all the iterations of $x^2+1$:

$p(x)=x$

$p(x)=x^2+1$

$p(x)=(x^2+1)^2+1$

$p(x) = ((x^2+1)^2+1)^2+1$
:

Comment: This is an [old problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h39570). Probably it is also in this website.

Comment: Ah, yes. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/271337/733250) they have it too.

Comment: @topeik Is your name Lucas?

Comment: @Sullo I wish. My name makes no sense.

Comment: @topeik How can I communicate with you?

Comment: You are already.